# How to get value_counts normalize=True with pandas agg?

Tags: python, pandas

This gives me counts of the # `my_other_var` that are contained in 'my_var'

`df.groupby('my_var').agg({'my_other_var' : 'value_counts')`

What I want is the percentage of 'my_var' that is comprised of 'my_other_var'

I tried this, but does not seem to give me what I expect

`df.groupby('my_var').agg({'my_other_var' : lambda x: pd.value_counts(x, normalize=True)})`

Comment: Can you add an example dataframe and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) :

```
df.groupby('my_var')['my_other_var'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```